# How to remove the stuff lists add when writing to textfiles

Tags: python, list

I need to write a list to a text file named `accounts.txt` in the following format:

```
kieranc,conyers,asdsd,pop
ethand,day,sadads,dubstep
```

However, it ends up like the following with brackets:

```
['kieranc', 'conyers', 'asdsd', 'pop\n']['ethand', 'day', 'sadads', 'dubstep']
```

Here is my code (accreplace is a list):

```
accreplace = [['kieranc', 'conyers', 'asdsd', 'pop\n'],['ethand', 'day', 'sadads', 'dubstep']]
acc = open("accounts.txt", "w") 
for x in accreplace: 
    acc.write(str(x))
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code and files as plain text, not as images.

Comment: Yes, and do use the code blocks feature, to distinguish code from prose.

Comment: What does `accreplace` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Since each element in `accreplace` is a list, `str(x)` doesn't help. It just adds quotes around it. To print the list in proper format use the code below:

```
for x in accreplace:
    acc.write(",".join([str(l) for l in x]))
```

This will convert the list items into a string.